# How can i build a nested HTML List from a flat list

Tags: c#, jquery, html, razor

I have a list of tuple that is passed from my model to my view. I am trying to create a nested HTML list using the list of tuple obtained from the model. My list is being returned in the correct order. It can be an infinite number if nested list items.

I trying to use a foreach loop to iterate over the list of tuple, however the markup just displays the `<UL>` right after each other and doesnt nest.

my foreach loop looks like this

```
        @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <ul class="nav-breadcrumbs">
                    <li>
                        <a href="@item.Item2">@item.Item1</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            }
```

i would like for each item to be a child of the previous item. I can change my model if needed. Or maybe pass the data to a javascript variable and build the nested list using jquery.
I want my mark up to end up looking something like this. and have it keep nesting

```
<ul>
     <li>
          <a>link</a>
               <ul>
                    <li>
                          <a>link</a>
                    </li>
               </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another (relatively simpler) solution would be creating the Html string on view before parsing as below:

Html parser wouldn't allow you to open all the ul, li tags first and then close all of them at the end, so you would have to go this way:

```
@{
     string html = "";

     foreach (var item in Model)
     {
       html += "<ul class='nav-breadcrumbs'><li><a href=" + item.Item2 + ">" + item.Item1 + "</a>";
     }

     foreach (var item in Model)
     {
        html += "</li></ul>";
     }
  }

  @Html.Raw(html)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Recursion, create a recursive method in your controller to create Html and pass it to the view through ViewBag, recursive method would look like below:

ItemType in the method parameters is type of your model list

```
public string CreateHtml(int i, List<ItemType> items)
  {
    string html = "";

    html += "<ul><li>" + "<a href='" + items[i].Item2 + "'>" + items[i].Item1 + "</a>";

    i++;

    if (i < items.Count)
      return html += CreateHtml(i, items);
    else
      return html + "</li></ul>";

    html += "</li></ul>";

    return html;
  }
```

add to ViewBag in your action as:

```
ViewBag.Html = CreateHtml(0, model);
```

On view show it like this:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Html)
```